# Extend the CUDA.@atomic enum to a custom struct

Tags: cuda, julia, atomic

i was wondering weather it is possible to extend the CUDA.@atomic operation to a custom type.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
using CUDA

struct Dual
    x
    y
end 

cu0 = CuArray([Dual(1, 2), Dual(2,3)])
cu1 = CuArray([Dual(1, 2), Dual(2,3)])

indexes = CuArray([1, 1])


function my_kernel(dst, src, idx)
   index = threadIdx().x + (blockIdx().x - 1) * blockDim().x

    @inbounds if index <= length(idx)
       CUDA.@atomic dst[idx[index]] = dst[idx[index]] + src[index]
    end
    return nothing
end

@cuda threads = 100 my_kernel(cu0, cu1, indexes)
```

The Problem of this code is that the CUDA.@atomic call only supports basic types like
Int, Float or Real.

I need it to work with my own struct.

Would be nice if someone has an idea how this could be possible.

Comment: Presuming you want an atomic addition, that isn’t possible. The hardware can’t do multiple atomic adds with one instruction

Answer (score 1):

The underlying PTX instruction set for CUDA provides a subset of atomic store, exchange, add/subtract,increment/decrement, min/max, and compare-and-set operations for global and shared memory locations (not all architectures support all operations with all POD types, and there is evidence that not all operations are implemented in hardware on all architectures).

What all these instructions have in common is that they execute only one operation atomically. I am completely unfamiliar with Julia, but if

```
CUDA.@atomic dst[idx[index]] = dst[idx[index]] + src[index]
```

means "atomically add `src[].x` and `src[].y` to `dst[].x` and `dst[].y`" then that isn't possible because that implies two additions on separate memory locations in one atomic operation. If the members of your structure could be packed into a compatible type (a 32 bit or 64 bit unsigned integer, for example), you could perform atomic store, exchange or compare-and-set in CUDA. But not arithmetic.

If you consult [this section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) of the programming guide, you can see an example of a brute force double precision add implementation using compare-and-set in a tight loop. *If* your structure can be packed into something which can be manipulated with compare-and-set, then it might be possible to roll your own atomic add for a custom type (limited to a maximum of 64 bits).

How you might approach that in Julia is definitely an exercise left to the reader.